# Get smallest value from a linked list?

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a piece of code which loops through a linked list and retrieves the smallest, but is not working. Instead it seems to be returning the last value I enter into the list...
(list is the head being passed from main)

```
 int i = 0;
    Stock *node = list;
    int tempSmallest = (list + 0)->itemStock;
    while (node!=NULL)
    {

        if ((list+i)->itemStock < tempSmallest)
        {
            tempSmallest = node->itemStock;         
            node = node->nodeptr;           
        }
        i++;
    }
    return list;
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `return tempSmallest`, no? besides, why do you iterate over list with `list+i`?

Comment: Is that a list or an array, as you are adding an index to it? With `std::list` you could use `std::min_element`

Comment: you are having and link list and link list doesn't have contiguous memory allocation. Try to iterate using list->next.

Comment: This code is dangerous. You're lucky you're not getting any `segfault`.

Comment: Actually, I'd say he would have been luckier if he had got a segfault.

Comment: Start with std::list<Stock> list;

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing `(list+i)` and incrementing `i` with every visited node for some reason. I don't know why you're doing this, but it's wrong. You basically traverse the linked list *and also* conceptually traverse an array (which doesn't exist at all). This is undefined behavior and cannot give meaningful results.

You must dereferece the currently valid node, not an array element that is a few indices after it somewhere in RAM, and advance by the list's next node pointer (I assume this is called `nodeptr` in your code?).

Something like...

```
Stock *node = list; // hopefully not NULL since I don't check in the next line
int smallest = node->itemStock;

while(node && node = node->nodeptr)
    smallest = std::min(smallest, node->itemStock);

return smallest;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct stock{
    stock *next;
    ...
};
```

this will be the struct of your nodes.
then when you initialize them, you should refer the next pointer of the last node added, to the node you're adding currently.
then the code will be like this:

```
stock *node = head; // the head you passed from main
int min = node->price;
for(;node;node=node->next)
{
    if(node->price < min)
        min = node->price;
    if(!node->next)
        break();
}
return min;
```